# R - subset data frame column using names in vector list

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to subset data frame columns  (into new df) using column names stored in the array of column names - like in c("col1", "col9", "col6")? I know I can reference one column in df using df[[colname]] syntax but it does not let me do it for multiple columns:

```
df
   X1 X2 X3
1:  a  1  3
2:  b  5  3
3:  a  3  4
4:  c  6  5
5:  c  2  2

cnm<-c("X2","X3")

df[[cnm]]
```

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

thanks

Comment: thanks - first one works but requires converting data frame into table ... second one did not work when I tried: > cnm<-c("X2","X3")
> df[cnm]
Error in `[.data.table`(df, cnm) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.

Comment: Second one will not work because your dataset is `data.table`

Answer (score 7):

Based on the OP's dataset, it seems like a data.table.  For subsetting columns in data.table, we need `with = FALSE`

```
df[, cnm, with = FALSE]
#   X2 X3
#1:  1  3
#2:  5  3
#3:  3  4
#4:  6  5
#5:  2  2
```

According to the `?data.table` documentation

> with - By default with=TRUE and j is evaluated within the frame of x;
>   column names can be used as variables.
>
> When with=FALSE j is a character vector of column names, a numeric
>   vector of column positions to select or of the form startcol:endcol,
>   and the value returned is always a data.table. with=FALSE is often
>   useful in data.table to select columns dynamically. Note that x[,
>   cols, with=FALSE] is equivalent to x[, .SD, .SDcols=cols].

If the dataset is `data.frame`, just

```
setDF(df)#convert to 'data.frame'
df[cnm]
#   X2 X3
#1  1  3
#2  5  3
#3  3  4
#4  6  5
#5  2  2
```

will subset the dataset

The `[[` is for extracting a single column of `data.frame` or `list` element

---

Applying the OP's code in a `data.table` gets the same error message

```
df[[cnm]]
```

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

If we do the data.frame subsetting option in `data.table`, it will not work either

```
df[cnm]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(df, cnm) :    When i is a data.table (or
>   character vector), the columns to join by must be specified either
>   using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table) or by keying x (i.e. sorted,
>   and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey). Keyed joins might have further
>   speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.

Comment: thanks - I missed setDF(df) ...